# Help with Shannon–Fano coding

Tags: c#, algorithm

Hello I hope some one will help me with this=):
I have a set of some numbers, I need to divide them in two groups with approximately equal sum and assigning the first group with "1", second with "0", then divide each group the same way in to subgroups until subgroups will be one of number from set!

Picture explaining this crazy things):
[pict](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/1/17/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0.PNG)

Comment: Where are you stuck? This seems pretty simple. The example you gave had no indication of "sums" within the partitioning step.

Comment: The algorithm is documented in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding basically it's an earlier version of the Huffman one. The values on the nodes in the OP picture are the the number of occurrence of the symbols.

Comment: i'm stuck right at  dividing numbers(frequencys) in to groups and sub groups and assing each simbol with binary code =\

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic algorithm, if you know C# it's pretty simple to follow. And the program print the partitions as it explore the tree.

Note that there are some possible bugs and the code is light years away from the quality that a teacher would expect from an homework. (As i guess that it is an homework... if it's for work it's even worse my code would be pretty much Daily-WTF quality)

But it should allow you to understand the basic algorithm structure knowing that :

- totalCount does the sum of the Count elements of the collection passed as parameter if you don't know Aggregate.
- The other Aggregate usage is there for display, just ignore it.
- I commented the sort as multiple elements have the same count and the C# sort function don't preserve order (And i wanted to get the same result as [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding))

The code:

```
var symbols = new[] {
    new Symbol { Text = "A", Count=15, Probability=double.NaN, Code=""},
    new Symbol { Text = "B", Count=7,  Probability=double.NaN, Code="" },
    new Symbol { Text = "C", Count=6,  Probability=double.NaN, Code="" },
    new Symbol { Text = "D", Count=6,  Probability=double.NaN, Code="" },
    new Symbol { Text = "E", Count=5,  Probability=double.NaN, Code="" },
}.ToList();

Func<IEnumerable<Symbol>, int> totalCount = 
    symbols_ => symbols_.Aggregate(0, (a, s) => a + s.Count);

var total = totalCount(symbols);
foreach(var symbol in symbols)
{
    symbol.Probability = total / symbol.Count;
}

//symbols.Sort((a, b) => b.Count.CompareTo(a.Count));

// Where is the Y-Combinator when you need it ?
Action<IEnumerable<Symbol>, string, int> recurse = null;
recurse = (symbols_, str, depth) => {
    if (symbols_.Count() == 1)
    {
        symbols_.Single().Code = str;
        return;
    }

    var bestDiff = int.MaxValue;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < symbols_.Count(); i++)
    {
        var firstPartCount = totalCount(symbols_.Take(i));
        var secondPartCount = totalCount(symbols_.Skip(i));
        var diff = Math.Abs(firstPartCount - secondPartCount);

        if (diff < bestDiff) bestDiff = diff;
        else break;
    }
    i = i - 1;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}|{2}", new String('\t', depth),
        symbols_.Take(i).Aggregate("", (a, s) => a + s.Text + " "),
        symbols_.Skip(i).Aggregate("", (a, s) => a + s.Text + " "));

    recurse(symbols_.Take(i), str + "0", depth+1);
    recurse(symbols_.Skip(i), str + "1", depth+1);
};

recurse(symbols, "", 0);

Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 78));
foreach (var symbol in symbols)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", symbol.Code, symbol.Text,
        symbol.Count, symbol.Probability);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll look through your code tomorrow and yes it's a homework ;)